# retention.ms not set on changelog topics created by WindowsStoreBuilder

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Kafka stream automatically set `retention.ms` and `cleanup.policy` on internal topics, ex. materialized KTables. However, I observed that `retention.ms` isn't set on logging topics created by WindowStoreBuilder.

Intuitively, I had say that logging topics are also internal topics and could / should be auto-configured. In my case, store has very short retention few minutes but default `retention.ms` is 5 days. Restoring a local store takes one hour while we only care about the last few minutes of data and older data will be evicted from the store.

Am I doing something wrong or should I explicitly set those config entries?

```java
        var retention = Duration.ofMinutes( 5 );
        var storeBuilder =
                new WindowStoreBuilder<>(
                        Stores.persistentWindowStore(
                                "name",
                                retention,
                                Duration.ofMinutes( 1 ),
                                false ),
                        Serdes.String( ), new JaegerSpanSerde( ), Time.SYSTEM )
                                .withLoggingEnabled( Map.of(
                                        TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, Long.toString( retention.toMillis( ) ),
                                        TopicConfig.SEGMENT_MS_CONFIG, Long.toString( retention.toMillis( ) ) ) );
```

If `retention` is increased in a subsequent release and changelog topic already exist, will topic configuration be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Internal topics are only configures by Kafka Streams when they are creates. If you change your retention time setting in your code, it won't update the corresponding topic config. This is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7591

As a workaround, you can manually reconfigure the changelog topic.

Comment: Thanks. What about the first question? Should kafka-streams set retention.ms or is it up to the application developer to do it?

Comment: If topic is newly created, Kafka Streams should set `retention.ms` for it. However, only for windowed changelog topics. For non-windowed changelog topic, that are configured with log-compation, `retention.ms` is not set as it does not apply.

Comment: I will try to reproduce my issue with a minimal test case and update the question. The changelog topic of my WindowStore created using a WindowStoreBuilder and passed to a ValueTransformer has `retention.ms` set to default cluster value.

Comment: Cool. Could also be a lurking bug if the configs are not set correctly.